# why cannot output the address of return directly in c++ by using `cout`?

Tags: c++

I am new to c++, and there is a problem that I find cannot directly output the address of return.

when I run `test03()` it occurs a error like below. But `test04()` works fine.

> C102:"&"要求左值

in English it should mean

> C102:& needs a left value

I have put script below, I think the return will be free if it not be used. But hope for a concrete answer.

```cpp
int change(int a) {
    return --a;
}

void test03() {
    int a = 10;
    cout << "the first address is " << &a << "the later adress is " << &(change(a)) << endl;
}

void test04() {
    int a = 10;
    int b = change(a);
    cout << "the first address is " << &a << "the later adress is " << &b << endl;
}

int main(){
    test04();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not using `&` correctly. you are trying to get the address of something called r-values. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lvalues-and-rvalues-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160

Comment: `change(a)` returns an r-value so `&(change(a))` is illegal because you can't take the address of an r-value (which your message is telling you, it needs an l-value)

Comment: You have worked with another language before C++ right? Variables in C++ are a bit different. Many language use mostly (or exclusively) references, so all variables "point at" the value in the memory. In C++, variables do not work that way, they are passed directly: the value is "in" the variable, and you copy it around by default.

Comment: The return type of `change()` is `int`, being returned by value.   It is described as an rvalue which means (roughly) it can only appear on the right hand side of an assignment.  For example,  `int x = change(3)` is valid, but  `change(3) = 42` is not valid.     Taking the address of an rvalue is not allowed.

Comment: From a practical aspect, allowing you to take the address of a returned value would prohibit returning them in registers, which is a pessimizing restriction.

Comment: So the explanation is `return` will be a value directly, not a **point** to a memory that saves a correspoding value. In a result it became a **rvalue** which can only be put in the right side?